# prove or disprove this statement If Bd(A) = ∅ .

Tags: general-topology

prove or disprove this statement

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and let $A \subseteq X$. If $Bd(A) = \emptyset$, then $A = \emptyset$ or $A = X$.

I think it is false and let $X=(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ and let $A=(0,1), Bd(A) = \emptyset$ I am not sure here is it equal empty set, but I do not know which topology I can choose for that. How about discrete topology, does that work? and is what I chose for $A
$ and $X$ correct?

Comment: Subspace topology works for your counter example.

Comment: but I do not take this topology before do you have other than it?

Comment: The  boundary of  A is empty iff A is open and closed.

Comment: The discrete topology will work.  All sets are open and closed so bd is empty.

Comment: Your counter example works on the usual topology.  As the points 0,1 don'don't exist they aren't limit points.  The only limit points are (0,1) itself so A is open and closed.  So border is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you on both choices.  I am guessing that when you write $X = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$, you mean those two intervals within the real line.  So you are talking about the *subspace* topology on $X$ inherited from the “usual” topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  (“usual” isn't a math term; you could substitute *metric* to be precise).

A smaller counterexample would be the discrete topology on a set of two points.

Comment: you mean my answer is correct and I can choose either one usual or discrete topology .?

Comment: @dr.rise Yes, you could choose either.  The two-point discrete topology has a minimalist allure to it, but as Justin points out in his answer, any disconnected space will do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the disjoint union of two planes with topology the disjoint union of their topologies. One plane is boundariless but not the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Take $X=(0,1)\cup(2,4).$ Then the boundary of $A=(0,1)$ is empty, since the boundary is the intersection of the closure of $A$ and the closure of $A^c$ (the complement of $A$), which is empty. So this statement is true when $X$ is connected.

Comment: what you mean by connected since I do not take it in my class.

Comment: Connected means that the space cannot be written as a disjoint union of two open nonempty subsets